# Redis low latency with 1k requests per second

Tags: nginx, lua, redis, low-latency

I'm using 2.8.17 redis server. Send requests throw unix.sock from nginx+lua.
Each request is one SMEMBERS command. Now I have about 1k req per sec.
In the nginx access log I see mostly next

```
[09/Oct/2014:18:04:49 +0300] [ 1412867089.670 : 0.002 : 190 ] 212.1.66.241 - - "POST /API/0.1/url/getCategory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29 
[09/Oct/2014:18:04:49 +0300] [ 1412867089.670 : 0.002 : 190 ] 212.1.66.241 - - "POST /API/0.1/url/getCategory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29 
[09/Oct/2014:18:04:49 +0300] [ 1412867089.670 : 0.002 : 190 ] 212.1.66.241 - - "POST /API/0.1/url/getCategory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29 
[09/Oct/2014:18:04:49 +0300] [ 1412867089.670 : 0.002 : 190 ] 212.1.66.241 - - "POST /API/0.1/url/getCategory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29 
[09/Oct/2014:18:04:49 +0300] [ 1412867089.671 : 0.001 : 190 ] 212.1.66.241 - - "POST /API/0.1/url/getCategory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29 
[09/Oct/2014:18:04:49 +0300] [ 1412867089.672 : 0.000 : 190 ] 212.1.66.241 - - "POST /API/0.1/url/getCategory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29 
[09/Oct/2014:18:04:49 +0300] [ 1412867089.673 : 0.001 : 190 ] 212.1.66.241 - - "POST /API/0.1/url/getCategory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29 
[09/Oct/2014:18:04:49 +0300] [ 1412867089.673 : 0.001 : 190 ] 212.1.66.241 - - "POST /API/0.1/url/getCategory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29 
[09/Oct/2014:18:04:49 +0300] [ 1412867089.674 : 0.000 : 198 ] 212.1.66.241 - - "POST     /API/0.1/url/getCategory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 37 
[09/Oct/2014:18:04:49 +0300] [ 1412867089.681 : 0.000 : 190 ] 212.1.66.241 - - "POST /API/0.1/url/getCategory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29 
[09/Oct/2014:18:04:49 +0300] [ 1412867089.681 : 0.000 : 190 ] 212.1.66.241 - - "POST /API/0.1/url/getCategory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29
```

You can see that request time is not more than 2ms.
But almost every second I have a few requests with request time about 100ms

```
[09/Oct/2014:18:05:22 +0300] [ 1412867122.843 : 0.131 : 190 ] 212.1.66.241 - - "POST /API/0.1/url/getCategory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29 
[09/Oct/2014:18:05:23 +0300] [ 1412867123.212 : 0.100 : 190 ] 212.1.66.241 - - "POST /API/0.1/url/getCategory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29 
[09/Oct/2014:18:05:23 +0300] [ 1412867123.613 : 0.101 : 190 ] 212.1.66.241 - - "POST /API/0.1/url/getCategory/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29
```

I can't find the problem place.

I checked everything from [the latency guide](http://redis.io/topics/latency)

Slowlog has no entries longer 5ms

System is not swapping

I don't use AOF

Answer (score 0):

If this really is the request time you are logging, then note that it includes the time to deliver the last byte to the client. Therefore your problem is likely the client connection. Since you seem to be testing this from one location, try adding more test nodes and debug the external network.

Comment: If I comment next line
    `local categories, err = red:smembers("categories:"..clear_url)` 
I don't have this problem. I think maybe it is the problem with unix.sock but I read a lot and it has not been confirmed. And if I understand correctly **set_keepalive** doesn't work with connection through unix.sock

Comment: If you suspect unix socket, then switch to TCP. Your base request time will go up, but it's the variation you're trying to explain.

Comment: What just came to mind is the data size. Any relation you can find with the side of the Redis response.

Comment: I had 1 mln records in the db. Than I made FLUSHALL but the same result.

Comment: redis-benchmark says that I can run a few tens of thousands of requests per sec

Comment: Then switch to TCP on localhost, and rerun tests. Redis does not report slow transaction so the delay occurs before or after.

Comment: Switched to TCP and number of the records with time request > 100ms the same.